# C: Ways to access system font through code, use it in BMP

Tags: c, gcc, debian, bmp

Is there a universal way to access a (debian) system's basic font symbols, and use them as uncompressed, 24bpp bmps/bmp macros?
I would need to do it using only standard C libraries and/or GCC preprocessor statements, and I'm not really sure what to search for on here.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "system basic font"? Console-mode fonts, or X11?

Comment: I' sorry, I meant console-mode fonts.

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97469/what-is-the-default-debian-ubuntu-console-tty-font-called) over on Ask Ubuntu, it provides a lot of detail about console fonts. They're not BMP-format (unsurprisingly, since BMP is a Windows format).